# NavigationViews with TabView and Signed in / Signed out state swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Here is the general structure of my code right now. Basically I am trying to make an app where a user has to sign in to use. Once the user is signed in, they will be taken to a tab view. Right now I am experiencing some issues where sometimes I will get double navbar/toolbars at the top of my screens. I'm worried that my current set up of NavigationViews is causing issues.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var isSignedIn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if isSignedIn {
                MainTabView()
            } else {
                WelcomeScreenView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeScreenView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SignUpView(),
                               label: {
                    PrimaryButton(title: "Sign Up")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainTabView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            
            SearchView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Search")
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            
            ProfileView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    Text("Profile")
                }
                .tag(Tab.profile)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Home")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SearchView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Search")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Profile")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried moving around the NavigationViews but that seems to only cause more issues.

Comment: Each TabView should have its own NavigationView (or better the newer NavigationStack), not the other way around.

Comment: Remove the `NavigationView` from the root of `ContentView`. Wrap `WelcomeScreenView` directly in a `NavigationView`

Comment: @Paulw11 I think that fixed it! Makes sense looking back at it since it would've been nested in that case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabView` must always be at the top it cannot be inside another navigation structure.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars

You can change your code to something like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var isSignedIn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if isSignedIn {
            MainTabView()
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                WelcomeScreenView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that `NavigationView` was deprecated in iOS 16 `NavigationStack` is a much better option.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types